# adding Border animations with dynamic classes in React with SCSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a `HeaverNav` component, a pretty simple fixed position header. When the user scrolls past a certain dimension a class is added that just adds a `border-bottom` to the existing class. Applying an animation for the border to enter is simple enough with a
`transition: all 300ms ease;` But having the border animate out when the class is no longer active is tricky. Currently the border just flips off suddenly with no smoothness, how can I achieve the effect of the border animating out smoothly?

**MY CODE**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import navStyles from '../styles/nav-header.module.scss';
import { MdOutlineAddBox } from 'react-icons/md';
import { RiHeartLine } from 'react-icons/ri';
import { FiSend } from 'react-icons/fi';

const NavHeader = () => {
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);
  console.log(isScrolling)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", () =>
        setIsScrolling(window.pageYOffset > 100)
      );
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav className={isScrolling ? `${navStyles.nav} ${navStyles.navIsScrolling}` : `${navStyles.nav}`}>
      <h1>Instagram</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><MdOutlineAddBox /></li>
        <li><RiHeartLine /></li>
        <li><FiSend /></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default NavHeader;
```

**SCSS**

```
@import "../styles/global.scss";

@font-face {
  font-family: "Instagram";
  src: url("../assets/instagram-font.otf") format("woff2");
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  background-color: $color-black;

  h1 {
    font-family: "Instagram", sans-serif;
    color: $color-white;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  ul {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;

    li {
      color: $color-white;
      font-size: $icon-size;
      margin: 0 0.5rem;
      transform: translateY(2px);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}

.navIsScrolling {
  border-bottom: $nav-border;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the ```transition``` property to your original ```nav```?

Comment: @AnthonyDev220 yes it seemed to have no effect